# Connection Visual Studio to Oracle 11g

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
OleDbException was unhandled by user code

There's an error to my connection from VS to Oracle using ASP.NET.
This is a log in form.

```
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"" +
        "Provider=OraOledb.Oracle; Data source=orcl;" +
        "User id=system; Password=Yadaqwe7;");
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    String ssql;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ssql = "select * from user_tab where username='" +
            TextBox1.Text + "' and userpwd = '" +
            TextBox2.Text + "'";

        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(ssql, cn);
        cn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the ASP.net components when you installed oracle?

In the universal installer there is a special selection for this and if not installed oracle will not work from ASP.net

Comment: I guess didn't. But where exactly in the universal installer? 
Should  I re install oracle again?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using 11.2.0.3 or greater has this flag 11.2.0.1 does not. Yes you are going to have to update your install to install this flag

Comment: I've already solved it. I tried to re-install the ODT with ODAC including all the ASP.NET components. There was just some missing concatenation operator on my OleDbConnection. I'm currently using Oracle 11.2.0.1 version. Thanks for the help bro!